# When you are going to ask someone about the amount of their bank deposit

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

Imagine you are going to find out how much deposit someone has in their bank account. I would appreciate it if you could tell me which one of the following self made sentences would sound natural in such a case to be asked:

> **a)** How much is your deposits?
>
> **b)** How much do you have in deposits?
>
> **c)** How much do you have in your cash bank deposits?
>
> **d)** How much deposit do you have in your bank account?

[This is a query between two close friends.]

Comment: Just curious, do you perhaps have a context for this? What is the relationship between the person asking and the person answering?

Comment: plz change final option to **d**

Comment: Thank you very much @ChaitanyaKumar. I've edited my thread.

Comment: This really borders on writing advice. Could you narrow down the specific language related issue? Your examples have too many changes between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of these is really appropriate, because [deposit](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deposit) relates to putting money into an account, not to the amount of money that is currently in the account. When talking about the amount of money in a bank account, we use the word [balance](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/balance).

If somebody were enquiring formally, they would say:

> What is the balance of your bank account.

Between friends, one would simply say

> How much do you have in the bank?

Answer (score 2):

How much do you have in the bank?

How much do you have in your checking account?

How much do you have in your savings (account)?

How much do you have saved up?

And as an aside, for Americans, this is a very social-context-specific question, meaning that, in most cases, one would consider it rude to be asked this. But I assume you are asking for socially-appropriate situations.

Comment: +1 for a good answer which I would add to by saying that it is a very social context specific question here in the UK too

Comment: @Teacher KSHaung you assumed it right. It was a query between two close friends and I had to mention it.

Comment: @A-friend, in which case, I would use the first one.

Comment: Which first one? My choice or your own choice @TeacherKSHuang ?

Comment: "How much do you have in the bank?" for between close friends in the US.

Comment: @A-friend: "How much do you have in the bank?" for between close friends in the US.